# use custom tokens on a webform email confirmation

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

I have written a custom module which defines some tokens. These tokens are used e.g. in Wysiwyg editor this way: `[mytype:closing_date]` (I have token_filter module)

Is it posible to make these tokens available also in the Webform module, and specifically in the confirmation e-mail that is sent after filling the form?

I tried `%mytype[closing_date]` but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

use also the [token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module, you'll find instructions in its [documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/token).

basically, you'll need to implement these two hooks:

```
function my_user_token_values($type, $object = NULL, $options = array()) {
  if ($type == 'user') {
    $user = $object;
    $tokens['name']      = $user->name;
    $tokens['mail']      = $user->mail;
    return $tokens;
  }
}
```

and

```
function my_user_token_list($type = 'all') {
  if ($type == 'user' || $type == 'all') {
    $tokens['user']['name']      = t("The user's name");
    $tokens['user']['mail']      = t("The user's email address");
    return $tokens;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented these hooks in my custom module which defines tokens (the hooks are named differently in D7 than in D6). But how to use them in the Webform e-mail confirmation?

Comment: hmm -- maybe here you'll find something .. http://drupal.org/node/627726